# Vue js beforeRouteEnter

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using laravel and vuejs for my app and every user has a role. Now I want to restrict users to access vue routes by their roles by redirecting them to another route if they can't access the page. I am using beforeRouteEnter for vuejs but I am getting an error

```
data() {
    return{
      role: '',
    }
  },
mounted() {
    axios.post('/getRole')
    .then((response) => this.role = response.data)
    .catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data.errors)
  },

beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    if (this.role === 'Admin') {
      next()
    }else {
      next('/')
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
app.js:72652 TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined
    at beforeRouteEnter (app.js:90653)
    at routeEnterGuard (app.js:72850)
    at iterator (app.js:72690)
    at step (app.js:72464)
    at runQueue (app.js:72472)
    at app.js:72726
    at step (app.js:72461)
    at app.js:72465
    at app.js:72711
    at app.js:72539
```

Comment: have your problem be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can't use `this` in `beforeRouteEnter` function,because before the route updates, your component's vm does not exist.
- in consideration of you put role information in your vm, you can use `next` to get your vm:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    // put your logic here
    if (vm.role === 'Admin') {
    }
  })
}
```

- actually,you should use the [Global Router Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/zh-cn/advanced/navigation-guards.html) ,and put your role information in global area,so that your can redirect your routing before your target component created